# WooCommerce get all orders in foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

hello i have this function it shows only 1 order details

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_reports', 'add_report_tab' );

function add_report_tab( $reports ) {
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );

    // Loop through each WC_Order object
    $items=array();

    foreach( $orders as $order ){
        if ( sizeof($order->get_used_coupons()) > 0 ) {
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $data = 'Order Number: #' . $order->id . '<br>' .'Order Status: '. $order->status . '<br>' . 'Order Creation Date: ' . $order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>' . 'Order Total: '. $order->total . '<br>' . 'Customer Username: ' . $order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'] . '<br>' . 'Customer E-Mail: '. $order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'] . '<br>' . 'Customer Phone: ' . $order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'] . '<br>'; 
        }

    }
    //return array($items);

$reports['reports'] = array(
                'title'  => __( 'Discounted Orders Reports', 'woocommerce' ),
                'reports' => array(
                    "sales_by_code" => array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Sales by Discount', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'description' => $data, 
                        'hide_title'  => false,
                        'callback'    => '',
                    ),
                ),
            );

return $reports;
}
```

This code displays [image]

how to make it display all the orders instead of just one order when i echo it shows about 7 order details but here it shows only 1 order

EDIT 1: The                         `'description' => $data,` 
is what shows the data under the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that you are overwritting your $data in each loop iteration.

Initialize data before the foreach loop with $data = "" and use then ".=" or $data = $data + "your code"

```
$data .= 'Order Number: #' . $order->id . '<br>' .'Order Status: '. $order->status . '<br>' . 'Order Creation Date: ' . $order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>' . 'Order Total: '. $order->total . '<br>' . 'Customer Username: ' . $order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'] . '<br>' . 'Customer E-Mail: '. $order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'] . '<br>' . 'Customer Phone: ' . $order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'] . '<br>';
```

instead of

```
$data = 'Order Number: #' . $order->id . '<br>' .'Order Status: '. $order->status . '<br>' . 'Order Creation Date: ' . $order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>' . 'Order Total: '. $order->total . '<br>' . 'Customer Username: ' . $order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'] . '<br>' . 'Customer E-Mail: '. $order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'] . '<br>' . 'Customer Phone: ' . $order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: @mohamedadel it's not `$order->id` but `$order->get_id()` (and `$order->get_status()` ) as since Woocommerce 3, properties are not anymore accessible on WC_Order Object, only methods are.